# SQL Server 2014 is not showing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, installation, configuration

I have installed SQL Server 2014 in my machine (OS Windows 10). I already have SQL Server 2008 R2. Now I have 2 server instances and I also have 2 Management Studios. My problem is that I can not access SQL Server 2014, even when I try from SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, it is opening SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.1600.1). I have tried with all the instances available.

Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Partha

Please find the picture below

[image]

SQL Server(**PARTHA**) is the name of the of SQL Server 2014 and is showing stop. When I am trying to start the server from SQL Server Configuration Manager, it is giving the error message showing in the picture above. And when I try from SSMS 2014 with the Server name **PARTHA**, it connects to sql server 2008 R2. The Old sql server (SQL Server 2008 R2) already has a server named **PARTHA**. Please find the picture below to find all servers in my machine.

[image]

Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Partha

I can not start the instance (PARTHA) from Services. It is throwing the above exception I have already mentioned in the picture.

Here What I have found in Event Viewer log:

*SQL Server is terminating because of fatal exception c06d007e. This error may be caused by an unhandled Win32 or C++ exception, or by an access violation encountered during exception handling. Check the SQL error log for any related stack dumps or messages. This exception forces SQL Server to shutdown. To recover from this error, restart the server (unless SQLAgent is configured to auto restart).*

And Sql Server log-file giving the following error:

*Stack Signature for the dump is 0x00000000DA02754D
Unable to create dump because SQLDUMPER library is not available.
SQL Server shutdown has been initiated*

Comment: Are you sure if you actually have installed SQL Server 2014 and not just the Management Studio 2014 ? Open SQL Server configuration manager and see how many SQL server instances are installed on your pc.

Comment: When you cannot access your database you must be getting some error message, can you show us the error message ?

Comment: @Partha this may help you taking care of your question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @Partha, Have you checked out default port number 1433. if you have two instances in one system.If both instances are using the default port then conflicts will arise.

Comment: @Partha, To avoid conflicts, configure one instance to use a non-default fixed port.

Comment: @Partha you service is stopped. The MSSQL Server engine isn't operating without it running.  Ports or no ports, nothing will work until you start the SQL Service.

Answer (score 1):

edit: based on your pic, your instance isn't even running.  Please start that service first.

First find your 2014 instance.  Open up powershell (start, run, powershell) and type:
get-service *SQL*

You should see 2 SQL Server Services, 2 agent services, and a browser service with a few others. Check to see what the service name is for the new 2014 instance.  The 2nd one you installed won't be default instance.  The Service Account however will have the instance name on it.  The instance is after the $ in the service.  So if you saw SQLSERVER$SQL2014Inst know that SQL2014Inst is the instance name.

Thus you'll want to connect like this in SSMS in the instance name:

hostname\instancename

such as locally:
127.0.0.1\sql2014inst
or
.\sql2014inst
or by ip
10.10.10.10\sql2014inst

Let us know how it goes.